# How do I use the node-tree-sitter module from typescript?

Tags: typescript, treesitter

From looking at pull requests & issues I see there are typescript definitions (possibly currently out of date) in the [node-tree-sitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter/pull/55) module; how do I access these definitions from typescript, and what would be the equivalent of the following node-tree-sitter sample javascript code in typescript?

```
const Parser = require('tree-sitter');
const JavaScript = require('tree-sitter-javascript');

const parser = new Parser();
parser.setLanguage(JavaScript);

const sourceCode = 'let x = 1; console.log(x);';
const tree = parser.parse(sourceCode);

console.log(tree.rootNode.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tree-sitter` module doesn't have a separate `@types/tree-sitter` module (like [some other modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html)) but instead bundles a [`tree-sitter.d.ts`](https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter/blob/master/tree-sitter.d.ts) type definition file with the `tree-sitter` module itself. You can find this file in your `node_modules/tree-sitter` directory. TypeScript finds this file automatically when you import `tree-sitter`. Thus you can rewrite the sample JavaScript code in TypeScript as follows:

```
import Parser = require('tree-sitter');
import JavaScript = require('tree-sitter-javascript');

const parser: Parser = new Parser();
parser.setLanguage(JavaScript);

const sourceCode: string = 'let x = 1; console.log(x);';
const tree: Parser.Tree = parser.parse(sourceCode);

console.log(tree.rootNode.toString());
```